# Why when dragging each time a Widgets SeekBar it's giving it higher number name and also give error in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

The seekbar after dragged it in the designer the bottom left show seekbar6 and also error that missing Constraints.

[image: seekbar]

and when switching to code I'm getting error on the SeekBar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/seekBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar6"
        android:layout_width="377dp"
        android:layout_height="18dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="21dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="355dp" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: error]

I tried in the designer to delete many times but it keep adding new seekbar with higher name like seekbar6 then seekbar7 and not just SeekBar

and keep giving these errors.

Comment: The error isn't related to the SeekBar version number, but becaust it is still not constrained; within the `ConstraintLayout`; it's position isn't defined yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I replicated your code in an xml, and in the same way at the beginning I got a constraint error message.

So, I added the Constraints manually

- **app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"**
- **app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"**

And also I did a **Clean Project** and then a **Rebuild Project**.

I attach the code and image of the layout that I made.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBar6"
    android:layout_width="377dp"
    android:layout_height="18dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: Screenshot]

Hope I helped with your problem :)